# Attributes.Add "onclick" for radio button causes javascript error

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

I have a radio button and I am adding the onclick event to that radio button like this:

```
rdo.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "SelectMeOnly(" & rdo.ClientID & ", '" & gvw.ID & "');")
```

The HTML it generates looks like this:

```
onclick="SelectMeOnly(ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_S1-2_ctl00_ctl16_rb1, &#39;S1-2&#39;);"
```

The error I'm receiving is "Missing ) after argument list".  I suspect it has something to do with the fact that it's converting the apostrophe into ' but I'm not a javascript expert at all.  Can someone spot the issue here for me?

Comment: your missing the single quotes for the first id, rdo.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "SelectMeOnly('" & rdo.ClientID & "', '" & gvw.ID & "');")

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick!

Comment: no probs, please upvote and accept my answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try using some backslashes before single quotes and you will the error is cleared.

Hope this helps!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the single quotes on the first parameter of the javascript function

```
rdo.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "SelectMeOnly('" & rdo.ClientID & "', '" & gvw.ID & "');")
```

Comment: It's best to flag typos as off-topic for being typographical errors.

Answer (score -1):

Per BhavO, needs single quotes around the first control

Comment: thanks, Ive added an answer for some credit, please upvote and accept, cheers.